# Animate div to the right side of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have the following **HTML**

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="portrait">
            <div id="photo"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
#portrait{
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
  top:20px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    position:relative;
  float: left;
}
#photo{
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  position:inherit;
  float:inherit;
}
#ppo{
  opacity:0;
  background-color:green;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  width:0px;
  left:30px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
console.clear();

    function photoOptions(){

        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "ppo");
        div.style.height = $("#portrait").css("height");
      div.style.top = $("#portrait").css("top");

      $(div).appendTo('#portrait').animate({ opacity: 1, width: "350px" }, 'slow');
    }

    $( document ).ready( function(){

      var timer = null;

    $("#photo").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#photo").css({"cursor":"pointer"});
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
          $("#photo").css({"cursor":"wait"});
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
           photoOptions();
        },600);
      },500);
    });

    $("#portrait").mouseleave(function(){
       clearTimeout(timer);
        $("#ppo").fadeOut("slow",function() {
          $("#ppo").remove()
        });
    });

    });
```

what I want is for the green div that appears to be a "perfect fit" to the right of the black border when it appears (same height). (for it to appear you have to hover the box). Any help on this one? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddles are your friend.
original
http://jsfiddle.net/NEBRZ/

You can do this purely in CSS
http://jsfiddle.net/ffsLC/

```
#portrait{
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
    top:20px;
    border: solid black 1px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#photo{
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    position:inherit;
    float:inherit;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:0px;
   -moz-transition: width 2s, opacity 2s, -moz-transform 2s;
   -webkit-transition: width 2s, opacity 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
   -o-transition: width 2s, opacity 2s, -o-transform 2s;
    transition: width 2s, opacity 2s, transform 2s;
}
#portrait:hover #photo{
    opacity:1;
    width:100%;
}
```

### EDIT:

I Understand a bit more what you want. I've left it as a CSS transition simply because it's more elegant http://jsfiddle.net/59Yfq/

Your original code has an insertion of an element. Rules of thumb: no need to create and manage elements in JS when simply a `display:none;` or `width:0;` will suffice. If you are using a table, use the table to your advantage

Comment: Honestly could be cleaned up a bit. I just merged the styles for the div you were creating with the image that already there

Comment: This might be closer to what you are looking for though. http://jsfiddle.net/jYQTM/

Comment: Hello dylan, ty for answering! Unfortunately what I really want is something just like this http://postimg.org/image/6j8yumqcj/ it should appear with left:30px of #portrait and animated... I don't know why I couldn't do it, something related with the "floats" I guess...

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer. With a table, there's no reason to `float`. I generally don't like tables, so if you want to read about floating with generic elements check these out: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: That's exactly it! But how should I do so that when I leave the black square AND hover the green thing it won't go away? That's why I was using jquery. I just needed to append it to #portrait and it would extend its body automatically, so whenever I left the black square to the green rectangle it wouldn't go away.

Comment: In which case Javascript was the way to go. You can tack on a class to make the magic happen or since you're using jQuery there's the nifty animate function http://api.jquery.com/animate/ Check the result http://jsfiddle.net/F9Hkk/